# Making underbrace text and comment text align

Tags: align

Hello I have tried to search for this question with several keywords but with no success.

Essentially, this is the final result I want to create: [image]

As you can see the "perfect square" is an underbrace and is on the same level as the "parentheses, and ..."

However, this is my current code and progress

```
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=x^2+16x+24&&\cmt{Given function}\\
&=\underbrace{(x^2+16x+64)}_{\text{perfect square}}-64+24&&\text{Complete the square: Add 64 inside}\\
&&&\text{the parentheses, and subtract 64 outside}\\
&=(x+8)^2-40&&\text{Factor and simplify}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

(ignore the red colouring, I can deal with that)

So I am wondering how to make them align on the same vertical level?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a top-aligned `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
f(x)&=x^2+16x+24&&\text{Given function}\\
&=\underbrace{(x^2+16x+64)}_{\text{perfect square}}-64+24&&
  \text{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
        Complete the square: Add 64 inside\\
        the parentheses, and subtract 64 outside
        \end{tabular}}\\
&=(x+8)^2-40&&\text{Factor and simplify}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh so that's also how to have "multiline text" in general? Thanks!!